# External Scripting and R (Kognitio)

Tags: r, kognitio-wx2, kognitio, wx2

I have created the R script environment (used this command to create it "create script environment RSCRIPT command `'/usr/local/R/bin/Rscript --vanilla --slave'`") and tried running the one R script but it fails with the below error message.

> ERROR: RS 10 S 332659 R 31A004F LO:Script stderr: external script vfork child: No such file or directory

Is it because of the below line which i am using in the script ?

```
mydata <- read.csv(file=file("stdin"), header=TRUE)
if (nrow(mydata) > 0){
```

I am not sure what is it expecting.

I have one more questions to ask.

1) do we need to install the R package on our unix box ? if not then the kognitio package has it

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem here is that you have not installed the R environment on ALL the database nodes in your system - it must be installed on every DB node involved in processing (as explained in chapter 10 of the Kognitio Guide which you can download from http://www.kognitio.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=3) or you will see errors like "external script vfork child: No such file or directory".

You would normally use a remote deployment tool (e.g. HP's RDP) to ensure the installation was identical on all DB nodes. Alternatively, you can leverage the Kognitio wxsync tool to synchronise files across nodes.

Section 10.6 of the Kognitio Guide also explains how to constrain which DB nodes are involved in processing - this is appropriate if your script environment should not run on all nodes for some reason (e.g. it has an expensive per-node/per-core licence). That does not seem appropriate for using R though.